# MS-ACCESS Delete Rows in ODBC Linked Table via "Pass-Through"

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007, pass-through

I have a a table linked to a ODBC table the ODBC datase Name is CUSTOMER_USER, The table's name is CUSTOMER_INFO, I need to use Pass-through to delete all the records in the ODBC Linked table "CUSTOMER_USER_CUSTOMER_INFO" if the date of thoses records are different from currentdate. I tried the following code AND selected "Pass-Through" in query design tab, but it always return error message

```
DELETE CUSTOMER_USER_CUSTOMER_INFO.*
FROM CUSTOMER_USER.CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE SUBMIT_DT <> NOW()
```

I also tried

```
DELETE CUSTOMER_USER.CUSTOMER_INFO.*
FROM CUSTOMER_USER.CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE SUBMIT_DT <> NOW()
```

or

```
DELETE CUSTOMER_USER_CUSTOMER_INFO.*
FROM CUSTOMER_USER_CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE SUBMIT_DT <> NOW()
```

or even

```
DELETE CUSTOMER_USER.CUSTOMER_INFO.*
FROM CUSTOMER_USER.CUSTOMER_INFO
```

None of the above works

Comment: What is the error message it is returning?

Comment: @Siyual it retuns "ODBC - call failed, ERROR: syntax error at or near "CUSTOMER_USER"; Error while executing the query (#7)"

Comment: Try removing `CUSTOMER_USER.CUSTOMER_INFO.*`  Your syntax should be `DELETE FROM Table WHERE Condition`

Answer (score 0):

Try this?  Included a NULL filter as well.  NOW() could get problematic.  DATE() should not. You might need to shut off the passthrough since DATEVALUE is a JET function though.

```
DELETE
FROM CUSTOMER_USER_CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE DATEVALUE(SUBMIT_DT) <> DATE()
    AND SUBMIT_DT IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: No, I need the Passthrough to modify the CUSTOMER_USER_CUSTOMER_INFO Table, because this table is an ODBC linked table in my current database

Comment: I was only concerned because I didn't actually hook the query to an ODBC linked table.  Did the query take as a passthrough?

Comment: My main concern was the use of Now vs Date.  Now includes time stamping

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had this problem as well.  One thing to be careful of are 1 to many relationships on the SQL Server with the table you are deleting from.  If there is a defined 1 to many relationship and you are trying to delete from the 1 side of the relationship, SQL server WILL preserve referential integrity and NOT allow you to delete from the 1 side if there are related records on the Many side of the relationship.

One more tricky thing is that is may not be immediately clear where to find these relationships.  You can look in the relationships button on SQL server BUT the problem may also reside in a DELETE trigger for the table on the one side as well.  So there are a few places to check.   You will either have to modify the DELETE trigger or manually delete the Many side records and then the 1 side records.  Good luck.